# How to start VbScript if someone access on my extern hard disk

Tags: vbscript

i have an extern hard disk connected with my router. Now everyone in my homenetwork have access to the external hard disk. Is it possible to start an vbscript if someone access my external hard disk?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to do this but they require that you change your design a little. The easiest way, would be to redirect the access of your external drive through a file server. (It could just be a Windows desktop).

Remove the share access from your external hard drive for everyone except your File Server, create a share on the file server that connects to this external drive, and have everyone use the hard drive through the share on the File Server.

Then you can get creative with scripts that monitor share usage like the link in
[this](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsNT/AdminTips/FileSystems/MonitorShareUsageforFileServerMigration.html) example.

This comes with the drawback that your file server will need to be on in order for the hard drive to be accessible.